# only keep distinct rows when doing collect_set over a moving windowing function in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Lets say I have a hive table that has 3 rows: merchant_id, week_id, acc_id. My goal is to collect the unique customers in the previous 4 weeks for each week and I am using a moving window to do this.

My codes:

create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_test_test (merchant_id INT, week_id INT, acc_id INT);

INSERT INTO TABLE table_test_test VALUES  
(1,0,8),  
(1,0,9),  
(1,0,10),  
(1,2,1),  
(1,2,2),  
(1,2,4),  
(1,4,1),  
(1,4,3),  
(1,4,4), 
(1,5,1),  
(1,5,3),  
(1,5,5), 
(1,6,1),  
(1,6,5),  
(1,6,6)
```

Then do the collect:

```
select 
merchant_id, 
week_id, 
collect_set(acc_id) over (partition by merchant_id ORDER BY week_id RANGE BETWEEN 4 preceding AND 0 preceding) as uniq_accs_prev_4_weeks
from 
table_test_test
```

The result table is :

```
    merchant_id week_id uniq_accs_prev_4_weeks
1   1   0   []
2   1   0   []
3   1   0   []
4   1   2   [9,8,10]
5   1   2   [9,8,10]
6   1   2   [9,8,10]
7   1   4   [9,8,10,1,2,4]
8   1   4   [9,8,10,1,2,4]
9   1   4   [9,8,10,1,2,4]
10  1   5   [1,2,4,3]
11  1   5   [1,2,4,3]
12  1   5   [1,2,4,3]
13  1   6   [1,2,4,3,5]
14  1   6   [1,2,4,3,5]
15  1   6   [1,2,4,3,5]
```

As you can see, there are redundant rows in the table. This is just an example, in my actual case this table is huge and the redundancy causes memory problem.

I have tried using distinct and group by but neither of these works.

Is there a good way to do it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct works good:

```
select distinct merchant_id, week_id, uniq_accs_prev_4_weeks 
  from
(
select 
merchant_id, 
week_id, 
collect_set(acc_id) over (partition by merchant_id ORDER BY week_id RANGE BETWEEN 4 preceding AND current row) as uniq_accs_prev_4_weeks
from 
table_test_test
)s;
```

Result:

```
OK
1       0       [9,8,10]
1       2       [9,8,10,1,2,4]
1       4       [9,8,10,1,2,4,3]
1       5       [1,2,4,3,5]
1       6       [1,2,4,3,5,6]
Time taken: 98.088 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

My Hive does not accept `0 preceding`, I replaced with `current row`. It seems like [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9412) or [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10555), my Hive version is 1.2. Yours should work fine with distinct added in the upper subquery.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Does Hive put the intermediary table `s` in memory? As I mentioned in the question, the goal is to avoid memory issues as my actual table is huge. Thanks again!

Comment: @PudgeSpammer No it does not. This is a subquery, not even an intermediate table and not in-memory. The whole query will be rewritten by optimizer and not necessarily it should be an intermediate step in the final plan generated. Check it using EXPLAIN command. If you have memory issues then please provide the execution log and I will try to fix. Of course it needs memory for collections, but not the whole subquery results, it should be able to parallelize on reducers.